# gatsby-plugin-react-leaflet with gatsby v3 - build error

Tags: gatsby, react-leaflet

I can't find any information wether the gatsby-plugin-react-leaflet (made for gatsby v2) is compatible with gatsby v3 or not, nor can I find any info on the build errors I get. I have tried everything ie checking if the window is defined, useHasMounted etc and nothing works. Seems to be something with this version of the plugin for gatsby. Any info would be great.

I get these errors when trying to build:

[image]

This is my the full code, if I remove the MapContainer and everything in it, Gatsby builds without problem.

```
import { Link, Icon } from "@myCompany/components";
import L from "leaflet";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { MapContainer, Marker, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import { useFetch } from "use-http";

import pin from "../images/pin.svg";

import * as defaultStyles from "./Map.module.css";

Map.propTypes = {
  styles: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string),
  address: PropTypes.string,
  street: PropTypes.string,
  zip: PropTypes.string,
  city: PropTypes.string,
};

export default function Map({
  styles = defaultStyles,
  address,
  street,
  zip,
  city,
}) {
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([0, 0]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const { get, error } = useFetch(
    `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=${address}&format=json`,
  );

  const getCoordinates = async () => {
    const response = await get();
    if (response && response.length) {
      const { lat, lon } = response[0];
      setCoordinates([Number(lat), Number(lon)]);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCoordinates();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return null;
  }

  if (error) {
    return null;
  }

  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const pinIcon = new L.Icon({ iconUrl: pin, iconSize: new L.Point(32, 38) });
    return (
      <div className={styles.component}>
        <MapContainer
          center={coordinates}
          zoom={17}
          className={styles.map}
          zoomControl={false}
          attributionControl={false}
        >
          <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
          <Marker
            position={coordinates}
            className={styles.marker}
            icon={pinIcon}
          />
        </MapContainer>
        <Link
          to={`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${street}, ${zip} ${city}}`}
          target="_blank"
          showExternalIcon={false}
          className={styles.link}
        >
          <Icon name="map" />
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nor can I find any info on the build errors I get.

It should be compatible with v3 according to this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/dweirich/gatsby-plugin-react-leaflet/issues/20) where the author's pointed out the backward compatibility with v3 and v4. Try using the latest version: `3.0.3`

Without further implementation details, I don't know what can be the cause of the issue.

---

The issue has been solved using Node 14.x and downgrading the package version to `2.7.0`, a version that exposes `Map` instead of `MapContainer` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for input, My question is if it's compatible with Gatsby v3. I'm using react-leaflet v3 already but the gatsby plugin itself says its made for Gatsby v2 so not sure if this is why I have problems. I updated my answer with my full code as well.

Comment: It's compatible with v3 (and v4). Have you tried using `import { Map } from 'react-leaflet'` instead of `MapContainer`?

Comment: Ok then something strange is happening here. This latest version of react-leaflet doesn't expose a Map only a MapContainer.

Comment: Some threads suggest running Node 14.x. Have you tried that? Or even downgrading the package to use `Map`

Comment: Thank you, downgrading to the version before the major re-write of the plugin solved the build issue.

Comment: I'm glad we figured it out. If the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvoting the answer to close the topic.